# rerender part of rich:popupPanel

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, rerender, popuppanel

I'm working with:

```
- RichFaces 4.2.2
- Mojarra 2.1.14
```

Lets look at simple code below:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{testBean.option}" >
        <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Option 0"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Option 1"/>
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="infoPanelId"/>
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    <a4j:outputPanel id="infoPanelId">
        <h:outputText value="Option 0 selected" rendered="#{testBean.option == '0'}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Option 1 selected" rendered="#{testBean.option == '1'}"/>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

and the bean code:

```
@ManagedBean(name="testBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable{

    private String option;

    public String getOption() {
        return option;
    }

    public void setOption(String option) {
        this.option = option;
    }
}
```

It works fine, and it is simple. Rerendering works as expected.
But if we place this simple code inside rich:popupPanel tag, that code will not work.
This is the code snippet:

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:commandButton 
        value="show popup" 
        oncomplete="#{rich:component('testPopup')}.show()"
        render="testPopup"
    />

    <rich:popupPanel id="testPopup" modal="false" autosized="true" resizable="false">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="popup"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <h:selectOneRadio value="#{testBean.option}" >
                <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Option 0"/>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Option 1"/>
                <f:ajax execute="@this" render="infoPanelId"/>
            </h:selectOneRadio>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="infoPanelId">
                <h:outputText value="Option 0 selected" rendered="#{testBean.option == '0'}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Option 1 selected" rendered="#{testBean.option == '1'}"/>
            </a4j:outputPanel>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </rich:popupPanel>
</h:form>
```

So the code inside popupPanel does not work. I cannot rerender part of popupPanel. So I have two questions:

1. why?
2. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Because by default `popupPanel` is shown inside the `<body>` element

2) Adding `domElementAttachment="form"` to the `rich:popupPanel` should help

Comment: Thank you Vladimir! You are right, and domElementAttachment does the trick.