# Selection of extendedDataTable inside popupPanel not in Ajax Request Parameter

Tags: ajax, jsf, datatable, request, richfaces

I am having a JSF page that contains a modal popupPanel from Richfaces and inside this popupPanel is an extendedDataTable. Now I want to have the user selection in my bean every time the user selects a new row. At first I want to show the code then I will explain the problem.

**Part of the xhtml page with the popupPanel and the extendedDatatable:**

```
<rich:popupPanel id="kontaktPanel" modal="true" onmaskclick="#{rich:component('kontaktPanel')}.hide()">

    <rich:extendedDataTable
        value="#{nachfrageBean.loadedKontakte}" var="kontakt"
        selection="#{nachfrageBean.selection}" id="kontaktTable">

            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{messages['tabelle.kontakt.instknz']}" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{kontakt.instKnz}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{messages['tabelle.kontakt.name']}" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{kontakt.name}" />
            </rich:column>

        <a4j:ajax execute="kontaktTable kontaktPanel"  event="selectionchange" listener="#{nachfrageBean.selectedRecord}" />
    </rich:extendedDataTable>

</rich:popupPanel>
```

**Corresponding bean with the listener and the needed members:**

```
public class NachfrageBean {


    private KontaktDTO kontakt;

    private List<KontaktDTO> loadedKontakte = new ArrayList<KontaktDTO>();

    /** DOCUMENT ME! */
    private Collection<Object> selection;



    public Collection<Object> getSelection() {
        return selection;
    }


    public void setSelection( Collection<Object> selection ) {
        this.selection = selection;
    }

    public List<KontaktDTO> getLoadedKontakte() {
        //contacts are successfully loaded
        return kontaktBusiness.getAllKontakte( );
    }


    public KontaktDTO getKontakt() {
        return kontakt;
    }


    public void setKontakt( KontaktDTO kontakt ) {
        this.kontakt = kontakt;
    }


    public void selectedRecord( AjaxBehaviorEvent event ) {

        UIExtendedDataTable dataTable = ( UIExtendedDataTable )event.getComponent();
        Object originalKey = dataTable.getRowKey();

        for( Object selectionKey : selection ) {
            dataTable.setRowKey( selectionKey );

            if( dataTable.isRowAvailable() ) {
                // do something with the selection
            }
        }

        dataTable.setRowKey( originalKey );
    }

}
```

The listener gets called successfully when the user selects a row in the datatable, but the selection is null, so I am getting a NPE. And when I remove the popupPanel and have my extendedDatatable directly in my page, then it works fine. I am always printing out the request parameters and I can see that there are two missing parameters when I have the datatable inside the pupupPanel. These request parameters are:

- mainForm:kontaktTable:wi =
- mainForm:kontaktTable:si = 3,3|3||x

So outside the popup the selection from the kontaktTable gets submitted but inside the popupPanel not. Does anyone know whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618500/rerender-part-of-richpopuppanel) .

By default the rich:popupPanel will be attached to the body and not to the form. Adding domElementAttachment="form" to the popupPanel just did it.